# Are bounded particles off-shell?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, energy, particle-physics

I have just been introduced to the concept of on/off-shell particles, and to my understanding, on-shell particles are those that verify:
$$E^2=(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2$$
Free particles verify this equation but, if I am not mistaken, the energy of a bounded state/particle is such that $E^2<(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2$.
If that is the case, bounded particles are not on-shell, and since they cannot be detected by instruments due to their bound status, how are they different from virtual particles?

Comment: Yes, it means the bound particle becomes virtual when freely propagates between moments of interaction with the external field.

Comment: So, bounded particles  are off-shell and there is no effective difference between them and virtual particles.

Comment: I think bound and virtual particles are not the same. Virtual particle is a particle in some intermediate state (for example, as an internal line of a Feynman diagram). Bound particle exists in a "real" state (it has definite energy), but it can be considered as a superposition of freely propagating states. The latter are virtual, because the particle spends only a fraction of time in each of them, then scattering on the external potential and going to a state with different momentum.

Comment: What people mean by "on-shell" are configurations which satisfy the equations of motion. For a relativistic free particle on-shell therefore means what you wrote. But a bound state presuposes an interaction and therefore your theory is no longer the free theory. So for the bound state the equation in question is violated, but because the interacting theory dynamics changes what we mean by "on-shell".

Answer (score 9):

It is a very good question. I will try to give an explanation based on section 7.1 *Field-Strength Renormalization* of *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory (Peskin & Schroeder)*. Due to the limit of my knowledge, my answer is far from comprehensive.

The major comments:

1. The physical states correspond to the singular points of the Feynman propagator in momentum space $\mathcal{D}_F(p) = \int d^4x e^{ipx}\langle \Omega | T \phi(x)\phi(0) | \Omega \rangle$. The virtual states correspond to regular points of the propagator.
2. One-particle states $p^2=m^2$ correspond to an isolated pole of the propagator. We often call them on-shell, because they are the major contribution to the LSZ reduction formula, which is used to calculate the cross section and  decay rate of physical process. So we usually assume that ingoing and outgoing particles in a scattering experiment are all on-shell.
3. States of two or more free particles give a branch cut (non-isolated singularities) for the propagator. They do not contribute to LSZ reduction formula.
4. Bound states give additional poles. Although we usually do not call them on-shell, they are physical states, not virtual states. Study of their physical effect is a rich and complex subject, but one that lies beyond the scope of a first course of QFT. In this stage, they can be neglected in most cases.

---

For a free scalar quantum field theory, the Lagrangian is
$$\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}\partial_{\mu}\phi \partial^{\mu}\phi-\frac{1}{2}m_0^2\phi^2$$
The Feynman propagator of the free field theory is
$$D_F(x-y) = \langle 0 | T \phi(x)\phi(y) | 0 \rangle = \int \frac{d^4p}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{i}{p^2-m_0^2+i\epsilon} e^{-ip(x-y)}$$
In momentum space, we have
$$D_F(p) = \frac{i}{p^2-m_0^2+i\epsilon}$$
When we say a particle is on-shell, we mean the four-momentum of the particle is the isolated singularity of the  Feynman propagator $D_F(p)$.

---

However, for a quantum field theory with interaction, the case is much more complicated. A detailed analysis can show that
$$\langle \Omega | T \phi(x) \phi(y) | \Omega \rangle_C = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dM^2}{2\pi} \rho(M^2) D_{\rm F}(x-y;M^2)$$
with 
$$\rho(M^2) \equiv \sum_{\lambda} (2\pi) \delta(M^2-m_{\lambda}^2)|\langle \Omega | \phi(0) | \lambda_0 \rangle|^2.$$
Here,$m_{\lambda}$ is the mass of one particular state. It is defined as the energy of the state in an inertial reference frame where the total momentum of the state is $0$. 
The formular is called the Kallen-Lehmann spectral representation.
In momentum space, we have
$$\mathcal{D}_F(p) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{dM^2}{2\pi} \rho(M^2) D_{\rm F}(p;M^2)$$
We know that $p^2=M^2$ is the singularity of $D_{\rm F}(p;M^2)$. The singularity of the $\mathcal{D}_F(p)$ is totally determined by $\rho(M^2)$.
[image: Picture from Peskin's book]
As we can see, the one-particle state is an isolated singularity of the propagator. So, $p^2=m^2$ is on-shell. States of two or more free particles give a branch cut and must be off-shell. Bound states give additional poles.
[image: Picture from Peskin's book]

In LSZ reduction formula, which is used to calculate the cross section or decay rates,  only isolated singularities (on-shell states) can contribute. The effect of branch cut can be neglected. As for the effect of bound states, it is a rich and complex subject, but one that lies beyond the scope of a first course of QFT. 
The section 5.3 of *An Introduction to Quantum Field Theory (Peskin & Schroeder)* discuss this topic briefly.

Comment: This seems a very sound answer, and I'm upvoting it, but I'm afraid I'm too early in my journeythrough QFT to fully understand it. I hope you understand if I don't close the question just yet.

Comment: This answer is far from comprehensive and my knowledge to QFT is also limited. I am looking forward to a better answer to the question as well. Thanks for your support!

Comment: Just a little clarification on terminology, the Feynman propagator IS the two-point function of the free theory by definition. You might want to refer to $\langle \Omega | T\{ \psi(x) \bar{\psi}(y)\} | | \Omega \rangle$ as a two-point function as Peskin does. So your item 1 in the list should refer to the two-point function not to $D_F$.

Comment: The branch cut is related to an off-shell multiparticle state. But this is not a bound state at all!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the answers given to be right.

Basically, I think since bound states are not limited to QFT and can be found also in non-relativistic QM, one has to either extend the meaning of off-shellness to non-relativistic QM or very superficially say that off-shellness has nothing "in particular" to do with a particle being bound or unbound as we know all particles are slightly off-shell due to infrared divergences.

I think that "being off-shell" is nothing more than tunneling in non-relativistic QM, namely: $E=T+V$ should be violated, in other words, particles should keep propagating even in the region where $E<V$.

But in the case of QFT and Relativistic QM, writing down the real equation for the energy of a particle due to a high degree of complexity is harder, which means writing $E$ in terms of $V$ and $T$ is not as trivial as NR QM, so one has to treat $V$ as a perturbation and treat the particles as freely propagating particles that are linked by vertices, which means each of these particles(lines inside a Feynman diagram) are supposed to obey the free relativistic particle equation $E^2=m^2 + p^2$.

But to take into account the "quantum tunneling" in this perturbative approach, one has to consider the possibility of violation of the aforementioned equation for each particle separately.

In my very perception, non-perturbative tunneling in RQM should look like, just the same as the NR QM, which is the dominance of the particle's Energy over the potential energy (and consequently exponential suppression in the coordinate space) but since we can't write down such an equation that differentiates $T$ and $V$ from each other easily(if there's any at all!), we take into account quantum effects(tunneling) in a perturbative manner(which considers all fields to be free ones, perturbatively).

Far off-shell particles do not propagate far from vertices and are exponentially suppressed(in time or in space) and only slightly off-shell particles can propagate and form the asymptotic states.

As one can see, the non-relativistic hydrogen atom, according to this definition can be off-shell or on-shell depending on $V(r)>E$ or $V(r)<E$.
The atom goes off-shell for $V(r)>E$ and it is quite on-shell for $V(r)<E$. As one can check it out, the energy eigenstates decay exponentially in space above a certain radius.

That radius is by the way the well-known Bohr radius.

Generally speaking, the atom is limited to the $E<max[V]=0$ region which is the definition of bound states (at rest) that finally results in the quantization of energy.

For me, the same applies to the case of the Hydrogen atom in QFT with the difference that there are contributions to the energy levels of the atom because of a new degree of freedom in which electron and proton can become off-shell. In other words, some fluctuations around the steady solutions of RQM that for example results in the de-excitation of an excited atom.

For sure the on-shell particles are quantum mechanical or classical depending on the theory, but being off-shell is a purely quantum mechanical feature.

Comment: I amended the answer so that it includes a comprehensive analysis of a generic bound state.

Answer (score 0):

My experimentalist's answer is that in quantum mechanically bound states as the total invariant mass is smaller than the sum of the constituent masses, the particles are off mass shell, as you state. This is deduced, one cannot measure individual particles in bound states  as one cannot measure virtual particles, as you say.

The difference is given in the other answer, virtual particles are a mathematical construct pertinent to internal lines in Feynman diagrams. Different tools are needed to study [bound states](http://www.helsinki.fi/~hoyer/Talks/HIP_Hoyer.pdf) with different mathematics, thus one just calls them off mass shell, and not virtual particles.

Comment: thanks for the answer above - I've asked a similar question in other places and been told that the off shell notion should be totally ignored (or doesn't apply) to bound states.

Comment: However, as you mention above, the particles can be considered to be off shell - is this due to binding energy?  What are the implications for QFT - aren't all 'real' particles supposed to be on-shell?

Comment: QFT is a particular tool, based on the postulates of quantum mechanics and, in particle physics , (there exist QFTs in other disciplines) based on  perturbative  free particle solutions of the basic quantum mechanical equations (Dirak, Kline Gordon, Maxwell). For closed solutions  with potentials there are unique wave functions, but they are few, as for the hydrogen atom. QFT is necessary to calculate the effect of potentials using the Feynman diagram formalism where the potential is in the exchanged dp/dt between particles  which is carried by the internal lines which have the quantumnumbers

Comment: of the named particle but are off mass shell and called virtual. Virtual particles are a mathematical construct and identified by being off mass shell. In that sense, mathematically, since the sum of the masses of electron and proton is less due to the binding energy, the electron and proton are off mass shell: they have the quantum numbers of the electron and proton but the mass is off for the exact solution. An infinite number of Feynman diagrams would have to be added in order to get the exact solutions of the hydrogen atom . QFT is the tool when no exact solutions exists

Comment: But the electron and proton in the hydrogen atom are not virtual (although they may exchange virtual particles). The quantum state defining the hydrogen atom has 8 degrees of freedom, yes?

Comment: That is, to form a hydrogen atom, you start with an electron and a proton The binding energy make the constituents off shell - but still particles... virtual particles are perturbative corrections (deltas in momentum space)...

The post above seems to suggest that the electron an proton are virtual, but as Eric Yang noted above, the resulting bound state is physical. 

So I'm not entirely clear on virtual particles being exchanged between particles (which particles, in the bound state?) and that the electron and proton are somehow virtual themselves, which I don't think can be the case.

Comment: @asimo The hydrogen atom can be completerly solved, there is no need for a perturbative expansion, and the word "off shell" describes four vectors with all the quantum numbers of the particle except that the mass is off shell. The same definition holds for the electron bound in the hydrogen atom.  As with all series expansions, it would take an infinity of  virtual exchanges to sum up to the clean solution with the  potential  quantum equation, (https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node501.html) . ( "still particles" can only mean the quantum numbers of the particles)

Comment: thanks - I'm still not clear though - **are you saying both proton and electron are virtual?** If I look at, e.g., A. Neumaier's excellent virtual particle FAQ, he make it very clear that they are a mathematical abstraction.

So I'm not at all clear on how a perturbative expansion would be performed (even though not needed). Potentials are exchanged *between* particles, so what particles exactly are we talking about here? What are the virtual exchanges between?

For a series expansion, you need real incoming particles, don't you? An expansion with virtual particles is an expansion of what?

Comment: sorry one more question - in the perturbative expansion case, we would have to have many different virtual electrons and protons, if we're doing an infinite series expansion, so it's not like we have a just two off shell particles.

Also see discussion here about why the term off shelf doesn't even really apply to bound states? https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/bound-states-and-the-energy-momentum-relation.926346/#post-5847021

Comment: @asimo  The term "off shell" means that the particle is not "real", you cannot put it in a magnetic field and measure its offshell mass. This is true for the mathematical abstraction of virtual particles, and for the hydrogen atom's electron and proton. The mass of  real hydrogen is slightly less than the sum of the masses of the electron+proton. So they have to be off shell, carrying their quantum numbers. The term virtual is used for the internal lines in Feynman diagrams  thus one does not call the electron and proton virtual, to make a distinction that no single Feynman diagram

Comment: can describe the Hydrogen atom. One uses different mathematical tools for different problem. We know that the hydrogen atom is made up by a proton and an electron. We know that the sum of their masses is larger than the mass of hydrogen, thus we have the concept of binding energy ( true for nuclear states too) and the measured fact that the electron and proton at any single instance would be off mass shell , if one were to compute a four vector for them  with a complicated quantum field theory system.

Comment: If I could do a perturbative expansion,  I would take the proton and electron as incoming and outgoing and exchange all sorts of loops  with elementary particles satisfying quantum numbers . The hydrogen would show up as a resonance as the energy is crossed, like the Z and other resonances  here http://pdg.lbl.gov/2015/reviews/rpp2015-rev-cross-section-plots.pdf ,  fig 50.5, (hairy for hydrogen because of the many energy levels)

Comment: Thanks @anna v - when you say not "real," what does that imply - not independently observable? Surely the electron and the proton exist, physically.

Comment: @asimo not real= not measurable

Comment: And yet, although not measurable as individual particles, measureable together in a bound state as the hydrogen atom?

Comment: @asimo  we trust the mathematical model we have developed from observations, i.e. that hydrogen is made up of one electron and one proton, because the model  has not been invalidated  and is predictive.